# Why in the iOS vue-resouce get request cannot accept the callback?

Tags: ios

I had embeded an HTML in a webview of iOS. I want to send a request of ajax with vue-resouce framework. The request is ok, but why in the iOS vue-resouce get request cannot accept the callback?

```
var vm = new Vue({
    el:'#check',
    data:{
        msg:'Hello World!',
        url:'http://localhost:8080/v1/user/check/'
    },
    methods:{
        get:function(token){
            alert(token)

            var realUrl = this.url + token

            this.$http.get(realUrl).then(function(response){
                alert('1')}
            ).then(function(response){
                alert(response);
                alert('1')
            });
        }
    }
});

function getToken() {
    var token = bridge.call("getToken")
    alert(token)
    vm.get(token);
}
```